# In neovim, can I use Enter to accept a command completion instead of executing the command?

Tags: neovim, command-line, autocompletion

Using neovim (v0.8.1 on Fedora 37) with its default configuration in my home directory, when I type `:e <tab>` the completion menu pops up, the first entry (here `Desktop`) is highlighted and the command line reads `:e Desktop/`. Say I am looking for `Desktop/foo.txt`. Intuitively I would like to hit Enter to accept the suggestion, then hit tab again to list the contents of `Desktop` (this is the default behavior of the fish shell). However, when I hit Enter neovim immediatly executes the command and starts editing the `Desktop` directory.

Is there a way to only close the completion popup when I press Enter (emulating `<C-y>`) and of course still accept the command on Enter when there is no completion popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution that gives the exact behavior I described:

```lua
-- init.lua
vim.keymap.set("c", "<cr>", function()
  if vim.fn.pumvisible() == 1 then return '<c-y>' end
  return '<cr>'
  end, { expr = true })
```